# Devise path conflict with CMS path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, comfortable-mexican-sofa

Am creating rails app with comfortable Mexican sofa and devise gem, in that devise path like

```
 http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

it is searching in cms_pages tables, how to solve this?

in my routes.rb file, i used

```
 ComfortableMexicanSofa::Routing.admin(:path => '/cms-admin')
 ComfortableMexicanSofa::Routing.content(:path => '/', :sitemap => false
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `ComfortableMexicanSofa::Routing.content` is defined last. It has a globbing route that clobbers everything defined after it.